# How to align a "Label:" followed by a RadioButtonGroup?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, radio-button, label, flex4.5

Please advise me, how to align Label followed by RadioButtons in Flex 4.5:

[image]

RadioTest.mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
               minWidth="955" minHeight="600">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:RadioButtonGroup id="_group" itemClick=""/>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:HGroup>
        <s:Label text="Playing tables:" verticalAlign="bottom" />
        <s:RadioButton groupName="_group" label="All" />
        <s:RadioButton groupName="_group" label="Vacant" />
        <s:RadioButton groupName="_group" label="Full" />
    </s:HGroup>
</s:Application>
```

There must be some standard approach to this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add `verticalAlign="baseline"` to the `HGroup`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
    minWidth="955" minHeight="600">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:RadioButtonGroup id="_group" itemClick=""/>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:HGroup verticalAlign="baseline">
        <s:Label text="Playing tables:" verticalAlign="bottom" />
        <s:RadioButton groupName="_group" label="All" />
        <s:RadioButton groupName="_group" label="Vacant" />
        <s:RadioButton groupName="_group" label="Full" />
    </s:HGroup>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. Does this use "labelDisplay" id, which I've seen in itemRenderer docs?

Comment: Excuse me, I don't understand your question. Please provide more details :)

Comment: Nevermind, I'm just confused by absorbing too many Flex docs :-)

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this with components in different groups?